# Request mixed with JSON strings and array fields, in custom function for reduction need Simplify/Refactory

Tags: performance, php, array, json

## Client

From a POST request I get a mixed structure of an array and JSON. To handle multiple type of elements I am using `var_dump` to get the passes. For `$_POST` I get this:

```
array(2) {
  ["json_data"]=>
  string(677) "[{"firstname":""},{"lastname":""},{"email":""},{"countryCode":""},{"phone":""},{"i_signup_password":""},{"i_signup_password_rep":""},{"email":""},{"i_signin_password":""},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"}]",
  ["other_data"]=>
  string(11) "Other_Data"
}
```

## Server

In PHP server side I am executing a function that reduce this `$_POST` to this array:

```
array(2) {
  ["JsonData"]=>
  array(10) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["countryCode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["i_signup_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["i_signup_password_rep"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["i_signin_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["form"]=>
    string(11) "d-sys-login"
    ["process"]=>
    string(8) "e-signin"
  }
  ["otherdata"]=>
  string(9) "otherdata"
}
```

## Code

You can see this [runs online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/415ba98a71e1c27300cc2946eaf803f9b8f15867).

Can someone help me simplify or improve the script?

- Application of best practices and design pattern usage
- Potential security issues
- Performance
- Correctness in unanticipated cases

The script used to meet this output is this:

```
<?php
    function buildVirtualData($data)
    {
        if (is_array($data)) { //check if is an array Walk trough to rebuild
            $temp = [];
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                $temp[$key] = buildVirtualData($value);
            }
            return reduArray($temp);
        } elseif (valJson($data)) { //check if is an JSON, Walk through to rebuild as an array
            $json_obj = json_decode($data, true);
            foreach ($json_obj as $key1 => $json_sub_obj) {
                foreach ($json_sub_obj as $key2 => $value2) {
                    if (is_array($value2)) {
                        $temp = [];
                        foreach ($value2 as $keyof => $valueof) {
                            $temp[$keyof] = buildVirtualData($valueof);
                        }
                        $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = $temp;
                    } else {
                        if ('true' === $value2 || true === $value2) {
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = true;
                        } elseif ('false' === $value2 || false === $value2) {
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = false;
                        } else {
                            $json_obj[$key1][$key2] = $value2;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return reduArray($json_obj);
            }
        } else { // if it is not an array or a JSON; evaluate the type if it is text and meets possible boolean values
            if ('true' === $data || true === $data) {
                $data = true;
            } elseif ('false' === $data || false === $data) {
                $data = false;
            }
            return $data;
        }
    }
    
    function valJson($var) //JSON Validator
    {
        if (!is_array($var)) {
            return ((json_decode($var) != null) &&
                (is_object(json_decode($var)) || is_array(json_decode($var)))) ? true : false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    function reduArray($array) //array Reductor
    {
        $result = $array;
        if (is_array($array)) {
            $check = true;
            foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                if (!is_array($value)) {
                    $check = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ($check) {
                $result = array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', []);
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
    //Example Data
    $_POST=[];
    $_POST['JsonData']='[{"firstname":""},{"lastname":""},{"email":""},{"countryCode":""},{"phone":""},{"i_signup_password":""},{"i_signup_password_rep":""},{"email":""},{"i_signin_password":""},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"}]';
    $_POST['otherdata']='otherdata';
    //Execution of Function hover $_POST Variable.
    $_POST=buildVirtualData($_POST);
    $_POST=reduArray($_POST);
    echo var_dump($_POST);
```

## Examples and Explanation:

Main function is `buildVirtualData`

This function tries to parse the `$_POST` variable; and seeks to reduce it; eliminating the excess of levels in the resulting arrays.

if you check the examples for this variable (arrays plus JSON) 2 arrays + JSON String:

```
    $_POST=[];
    $_POST['JsonData']='[{"firstname":""},{"lastname":""},{"email":""},{"countryCode":""},{"phone":""},{"i_signup_password":""},{"i_signup_password_rep":""},{"email":""},{"i_signin_password":""},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"}]';
    $_POST['otherdata']='otherdata';
```

the output, Check that this include 2 Main `array` :: `JsonData`and `otherdata`:

```
array(2) {
  ["JsonData"]=>
  array(10) {
    ["firstname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["lastname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["email"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["countryCode"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["phone"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["i_signup_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["i_signup_password_rep"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["i_signin_password"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["form"]=>
    string(11) "d-sys-login"
    ["process"]=>
    string(8) "e-signin"
  }
  ["otherdata"]=>
  string(9) "otherdata"
}
```

While for this other variable (Only one `array` with `JSON` String):

```
    $_POST=[];
    $_POST['JsonData']='[{"firstname":""},{"lastname":""},{"email":""},{"countryCode":""},{"phone":""},{"i_signup_password":""},{"i_signup_password_rep":""},{"email":""},{"i_signin_password":""},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"},{"form":"d-sys-login"},{"process":"e-signin"}]';
```

the result is one less array level in this case (removing the `JsonData` index which is unnecessary in this scope):

```
array(10) {
  ["firstname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["lastname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["countryCode"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["phone"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["i_signup_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["i_signup_password_rep"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["i_signin_password"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["form"]=>
  string(11) "d-sys-login"
  ["process"]=>
  string(8) "e-signin"
}
```

**the other 2 Function used:**

`valJson` is to validate if value is an `JSON String` and can be used as `Object` or `Array`.

`reduArray` is the function that performs a reduction of each `Array`.

**Why a function that does all this?**

I don't have control of the javascript code, I can only offer solutions in php code; What I can do is verify each scenario of what the server receives and this is the slightly more complex script I have.

in fact the `JsonData` index is not relevant take care of this: according to the documentation, everything that comes inside `JsonData` (the String Json) will be the inputs filled in a form and their value associated, so in reality the string is more important; and that the indexes and string values become `indexes` of `$_POST` ...

for example: there is a form with multiple checkboxes, they can be around 600 in total! Let's say they are to manage the permissions of the process screen and each process screen has 10 possible permission buttons, which are defined according to whether the checkbox is checked or not; There is no way that the server supports sending 600+ inputs in a single request without manipulating the server...

so the ingenious javascript programmer decided to put the 600 input and their filled values (formatted as string) inside a `JSON` variable (`JsonData` index / array) to be able to pass them to the server. I assure you, I do not share this idea; but need work around this.

**These results are correct, but I am looking to improve the code based on the objectives of this community.**

Comment: So how convoluted might your incoming data be?  Do you _actually_ need to have recursion while converting arrays of arrays to associative arrays? or will your data only have a maximum depth of 2?  Knowing the business requirements will go a long way in lightening the load of the code logic.

Comment: I need to be more sure about your incoming data and your requirements.  Will this simple handling suffice?  https://3v4l.org/4ms0W  If so, I can post an educational explanation.

Comment: for your first comment: I don't know how deep the arrays are, even knowing this point as a dynamic part I resorted to recursion for ... this is possible for arrays, I don't know if JSON string can be nested.

Comment: for your second comment: I have verified your script but the last 2 array fixes lost the index, and this is not one of the goals. Although it looks quite simple, but I also see that it does not evaluate Booleans, this is one of the points to achieve.

Comment: @mickmackusa as I comment in the post; the script output is correct; the improvement I'm looking for is in the script.

Comment: "the last 2 array fixes lost the index" ... no they didn't, I just wasn't printing them.  See this change: https://3v4l.org/g5TVf  Perhaps provide a battery of sample inputs that isolate all of the behaviours of your script.  Some booleans, some mixed data, some multi-dimensional data -- then we can run your script and see what output is expected.

Comment: @mickmackusa ok this example preserves the index of the second and third perfect; but if the array has a unique JSON string in a single array, it also keeps the first index which is not correct, for this scenario the script is expected to reduce the array and drop the first index, check Example 2 of output an your version script ouput : https://3v4l.org/KWPn8

Comment: Then you are developing a "lossy" data flattener.  You are asking for the script to kill an associative key -- which should be, by definition, "valuable data".  I do not have time to discuss right now, please edit your question.

Comment: in fact the `JsonData` index is not relevant: according to the documentation, everything that comes inside `JsonData` (the String Json) will be the `inputs` filled in a form and their `value` associated, so in reality the `string` is more important; and that the indexes and string values become indexes of `$_POST` ...

Comment: for example: there is a form with multiple checkboxes, they can be around 600 in total! Let's say they are to manage the permissions of the process screen and each process screen has 10 possible permission buttons, which are defined according to whether the checkbox is checked or not; There is no way that the server supports sending 600+ inputs in a single request without manipulating the server;

Comment: so the ingenious javascript programmer decided to put the 600 input and their filled values (formatted as string) inside a JSON variable (JsonData index / array) to be able to pass them to the server. I assure you, I do not share this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, virtually all of that over-engineered convolution can be scrapped.

You only need to take special action when you process the `JsonData` value.

It needs to be decoded, flattened, and merged with the other non-encoded data.

Simply use something like this: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Ku53H))

```
$post = [];
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if ($key !== 'JsonData') {
        $post[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $post = array_merge($post, ...json_decode($value, true));
    }
}
var_export($post);
```

If you are concerned about redundant subarray keys (that were previously json encoded), then that is more of a problem with the incoming data rather than a problem with this process (my script provides the same handling as in your posted script).

Now that you can see how simply the data can be unpacked, you won't need to bag so hard on the other developer.

---

I don't think I endorse the practice of key-ignorant json decoding `true`/`false` strings to booleans because it will potentially convert strings that shouldn't be converted.

Amyhow, here's one way of handling the conditional boolean conversion ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/DLiqu)):

```
function mergeAndBoolify($posted) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($posted as $key1 => $value1) {
        if ($key1 === 'JsonData') {
            foreach (json_decode($value1, true) as $item) {
                foreach ($item as $key2 => $value2) {
                    if (in_array($value2, ['true', 'false'])) {
                        $value2 = json_decode($value2);
                    }
                    $result[$key2] = $value2;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $result[$key1] = $value1;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$_POST = [
    'JsonData' => '[{"firstname":"false"},{"lastname":"true"},{"email":""}]',
    'otherdata' => 'otherdata'
];

var_export(mergeAndBoolify($_POST));
```

Output:

```
array (
  'firstname' => false,
  'lastname' => true,
  'email' => '',
  'otherdata' => 'otherdata',
)
```

Comment: ok but how i can get it with every value evaluated is a bolean (true, false), including string like 'true', 'false'...

Comment: Please provide sample data for this case and your exact required result.  I can only understand the variability of the data based on what you provide.

Comment: @walter, I have updated my answer to covert boolean strings within the jsondata to boolean type.

Comment: thank ypur for the great help.